# Using Unicode in CHtmlEditCtrl::SetDocumentHTML

Tags: c++, mfc

How do I use [`CHtmlEditCtrl::SetDocumentHTML`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/chtmleditctrlbase-class?view=vs-2019#setdocumenthtml) to display Unicode correctly (either UTF-16 or UTF-8 input)

Program is compiled in Unicode.

For example, given the following input with `charset=utf-8` meta tag:

```
CString u16 = LR"(<!DOCTYPE><html>
    <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/></head>
    <body>ελληνικά 华语 </body></html>)";
```

`m_htmledit.SetDocumentHTML(u16)` doesn't show the characters correctly.

Instead, I have to call `m_htmledit.SetDocumentHTML(CA2W(CW2A(u16, CP_UTF8), CP_ACP));`

I can't figure out why it works like that, or if it does work on all systems.

Minimum example:

```
#include "afxhtml.h"
...
CHtmlEditCtrl m_htmledit;
...
BOOL CMyDialog::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();
    m_htmledit.Create(0, 0, CRect(10, 10, 300, 300), this, 0, 0);

    //wait for the control, this is not directly related to the question
    CComPtr<IHTMLDocument2> document;
    if(m_htmledit.GetDHtmlDocument(&document))
    {
        CComBSTR ready;
        while(document->get_readyState(&ready) == S_OK)
            if(wcscmp(ready, L"complete") == 0 || !AfxPumpMessage())
                break;
    }

    //send html data:
    CString utf16 = LR"(<!DOCTYPE><html>
        <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/></head>
        <body>ελληνικά 华语 </body></html>)";

    //m_htmledit.SetDocumentHTML(utf16); <- outputs garbage characters
    m_htmledit.SetDocumentHTML(CA2W(CW2A(utf16, CP_UTF8), CP_ACP)); //<- correct output
    return TRUE;
}
```

There is similar issue with UTF-8 input.

`m_htmledit_ctrl.SetDocumentHTML(CA2W(utf8, CP_UTF8));` doesn't show the characters correctly.

`m_htmledit_ctrl.SetDocumentHTML(CA2W(utf8, CP_ACP));` does work. But using `CP_ACP` here is odd.

Example:

```
CStringA utf8 = u8R"(<!DOCTYPE><html>
    <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/></head>
    <body>ελληνικά 华语 </body></html>)";
m_htmledit.SetDocumentHTML(CA2W(utf8, CP_ACP)); //<= correct output
```

Comment: Did you validate that your `utf8` variable really does hold properly encoded UTF-8 data before converting it to UTF-16?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, the variable is correct. I added minimum example.

Comment: In the line `m_htmledit_ctrl.SetDocumentHTML(CString(CA2W(utf8, CP_UTF8)));` aren't you trying to convert utf-8 to utf-8? My understanding is that CP_UTF8 is a typedef for the utf8 code page. Since utf16 has code page 1200, what happens when you try `m_htmledit_ctrl.SetDocumentHTML(CString(CA2W(utf8, 1200)));`

Comment: @AllanCameron `CA2W` converts `char` data to `wchar_t`, the codepage is the *source* codepage of the `char` data

Comment: @BarmakShemirani what happens if you remove `CString`? `m_htmledit_ctrl.SetDocumentHTML(CA2W(utf8, CP_UTF8));`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Same result. I don't know why I put `CString` in there, it's not doing anything. I'll remove it in edit.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani you definitely should not need to do `CA2W(CW2A(utf16, CP_UTF8), CP_ACP)`. The fact that `SetDocumentHTML(utf16)` doesn't work correctly is troubling. Even though you are building your app for Unicode, `SetDocumentHTML()` is acting like it wants ANSI data, which it shouldn't. So focus on why UTF-16 is not working, take UTF-8 out of the equation completely

Comment: @RemyLebeau Good point. UTF-8 was a bit of distraction. I edited the question slightly.

Comment: @AllanCameron I put an extra `CString` in there, I should be `m_htmledit_ctrl.SetDocumentHTML(CA2W(utf8, CP_UTF8))` (edited the question) but same result. `1200` is not a valid code for that function and throws an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CHtmlEditCtrl::SetDocumentHTML` uses a class called `CStreamOnCString`.

`CStreamOnCString` at some point calls

```
m_strAnsi = m_strStream;
```

Where `m_strAnsi` is a storage buffer, and `m_strStream` is `CStringW` source. I believe this is an error, because it doesn't copy source to the buffer. Rather it converts it with `CW2A(m_strStream, CP_ACP)`

This error can be corrected with another `CP_ACP` conversion prior to sending data.

Alternatively we can write our own function as follows:

```
class CMyHtmlEditCtrl : public CHtmlEditCtrl
{
    public:
    template <class Type>
    HRESULT SetDocumentHTML_unicode(CStringT<Type, StrTraitMFC<Type>> html)
    {
        HRESULT hr = E_NOINTERFACE;
        CComPtr<IHTMLDocument2> document;
        if(!GetDHtmlDocument(&document))
            return hr;
        IStream *istream = SHCreateMemStream(
          reinterpret_cast<const BYTE*>(html.GetBuffer()), sizeof(Type)*html.GetLength());
        if(istream)
        {
            //CComQIPtr<IPersistStreamInit> psi = document; 
            CComQIPtr<IPersistStreamInit> psi { document }; //c++20 compliant
            if(psi)
                hr = psi->Load(istream);
            istream->Release();
        }
        html.ReleaseBuffer();
        return hr;
    }
};
```

Now we can call `SetDocumentHTML_unicode(utf8_string)` or `SetDocumentHTML_unicode(utf16_string)`

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer does not compile in c++20. Here is a version that does (however only for CStringW or CStringA, depending on UNICODE define):

```
HRESULT CMyHtmlEditCtrl::SetDocumentHTML_unicode(CString html)
{
    HRESULT hr = E_NOINTERFACE;
    CStreamOnCString stream(html);
    ::ATL::CComPtr<IHTMLDocument2> spHTMLDocument;
    ::ATL::CComQIPtr<IPersistStreamInit> spPSI;

    if(!GetDHtmlDocument(&spHTMLDocument))
        return hr;
    IStream *istream = SHCreateMemStream(
        reinterpret_cast<const BYTE*>((LPCTSTR)html), sizeof(TCHAR)*html.GetLength());
    if(istream)
    {
        spPSI = spHTMLDocument;
        if(spPSI)
            hr = spPSI->Load(istream);
        istream->Release();
    }
    return hr;
}
```

Comment: It needed the correct initializer for c++20, fixed it.